# Odoo website controller update html/template

Tags: controller, web, odoo-8, odoo

Hi I'd like to make a button visible/invisible from inside a website Controller.

```
@http.route(['/shop/cart/update_json'], type='json', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
def cart_update_json(self, product_id, line_id=None, add_qty=None, set_qty=None, display=True):
    if test > 0:
        button_visible = True
    else:
        button_visible = False
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be very hard.

First, you need to think where the button will be located. For example, if it is product page in the shop, you would have to inherit id website_sale.product.

Secondly, insert a script or simply use a conditional statement available in the framework (t-if). For example, if you want to hide the button if user is not logged in then you would use 
`<t t-if="uid is None">` (if user id is non - user is not logged in).

Those principles are working on all versions of Odoo. I have made a module that changes the button if the user is not signed:
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/hide_price_shop/

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

yes return the boolean as json and on templates just check whether its true.
for eg:

```
<button t-if="object.button_visible" .. />
```

Comment: This only works when loading the page, I'd like to update the condition based on the total price in the website cart. This total price is updated by Ajax, so I guess I need to look there